# Azure container instance is automatically stopping after few seconds

Tags: azure, docker, containers, solace, azure-container-instances

I am new to Azure Container Instances, I created an azure container with public docker image of Solace form Docker Hub(https://hub.docker.com/r/solace/solace-pubsub-standard).

Process completed without error, but instance is automatically stopping after few seconds. I started manually but it automatically got stopped again. There is no error in logs for container or in instance activity.

Any input will help...

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? I didn't see any response.

Comment: @CharlesXu Sorry, got pulled in different work not able to look in to it now. Will check again later...

Comment: Do you already check it? I don't see any updates for serial days.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, you can figure out that the logs of the container already shows the error:

[image]

And when you run the image in your local Docker server without the parameter `--shm-size 2g`, then it also terminates with the same error. So I think it's the reason that the container instance terminated. And as I know, the ACI does not support the `--shm-size` right now.